# serial program faster then parallel fortran

Tags: linux, fortran, mpi, gfortran

I try to test a fortran [MPI program](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/samples/Fortran/mpi_pi_reduce.f) to see how much speed I can gain from MPI respect serial programming.

I first compile the program with:

`mpif90 mpi_pi_reduce.f -o mpi_pi`

and then, because I had problem in localize the `mpirun` I launch the program as follow:

`/usr/bin/mpirun -np 4 ./mpi_pi`

Now, with np=1 I obtain:

```
real    0m0.063s
user    0m0.049s
sys     0m0.017s
```

while if I use np=4 I obtain:

```
real    0m1.139s
user    0m0.352s
sys     0m0.045s
```

Which is unrealistic :-( ! 
Is it possible that, using  `/usr/bin/mpirun`, the MPI doesn't work properly? I do not touch the example code so the problem can not be the program itself.
I have  ifort:

`ifort (IFORT) 14.0.1 20131008
Copyright (C) 1985-2013 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.`

and gfortran:

`GNU Fortran (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Finally:

`/usr/bin/mpirun -V
mpirun (Open MPI) 1.4.5`

The error I had, using only `mpirun` command, was:

`/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.1.106/mpirt/bin/intel64/mpirun: 96: .: Can't open /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.1.106/mpirt/bin/intel64/mpivars.sh`

This is the reason why I use the `/usr/bin/mpirun` to launch the code as suggested [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-clusters-and-hpc-technology/topic/474091).

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: And if you set `np=2` ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark it give to me `real 0m0.082s
user 0m0.102s
sys 0m0.040s` with oscillations between 0.072 to 0.084 if I re-run it several time.

Comment: Isn't this "user" time the sum of all the time spent by each processor (so linearly increasing with the number of procs)? Also, the linked MPI program seems to be doing completely the same calculation on each processor unless random_seed() gives different random-number sequences... (so the result is always the same).

Answer (score 5):

Your test takes 0m0.063s with a single core !

You will never be able to get any reasonable timings with such a short benchmark : communications are expensive, typically 1 microsecond for a one-sided interprocess communication on the same host, whereas a floating-point operation is in the order of the nanosecond. If you add the time you wait in barriers, etc, you see that inter-process communication is not at all the same granularity as in shared memory.

By increasing the ROUNDS variable in your program, you should try to target benchmarks with at least 10 seconds for the fastest run in order to eliminate the time spent in initialization and finalization.

Note that MPI_REDUCE is an expensive call, where the time it takes increases with the total number of processes (as opposed to MPI_SEND for example). You should move it outside of the loop to make much more computations than communication.

If your goal is not learning MPI but parallelizing a Monte Carlo code (or some "embarrassingly parallel" code), you should have a look at the ZeroMQ library (http://zeromq.org) which has bindings in many languages including Fortran. With this library you will get fault tolerance (if one process crashes, your run continues), and the possibility to have flexible resources (you can attach and detach clients whenever you want). This is very useful because you don't need to wait for all the resources to be free on the cluster before your calculation starts. Just submit multiple jobs that connect to the same server! You can
check out these slides : http://irpf90.ups-tlse.fr/files/parallel_programming.pdf where you have a client/server implementation of Pi using pipes, sockets and XML/RPC. You can do the same using Fortran and ZeroMQ with no effort.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have one error message to work with you will want to find out why it can't open `/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.1.106/mpirt/bin/intel64/mpivars.sh`.

Check this file exists and check the permissions on it allow it to be executed by whatever user is running the process.

Comment: I search inside the path `/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.1.106/mpirt/bin/intel64` but I didn't find the mpivars.sh I also follow this link https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/missing-mpivarsh-error but I can not locate the directory impi maybe the problem was this missing directory?

Comment: A fix to this particular error (not necessarily your problem) would be to provide that file and directory, but does not tell you what caused the problem in the first place.